# Cannot specify probability function for extraTrees model in caret package

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

everyone,

Recently, I have been using extraTrees model in caret package. However, I noticed that the probability function for extraTrees model is set to NULL by using the following scripts:

```
extratrees_para <- getModelInfo('extraTrees', regex = F)[[1]]

extratrees_para$prob
```

I noticed that in the original package of extraTress, it can be used to generate probability prediction for classification problems. So I'd like to specify the prob function for extratrees_para.

```
extratrees_para$prob <- function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL){
as.data.frame(predict(modelFit, newdata, probability = TRUE))
}
extratrees_para$type <- 'Classification'
```

Then I construct train function to build the model

```
extratreesGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry=1:2,
                      .numRandomCuts=1)

  modelfit_extratrees <- train(outcome~., data=training_scaled_sel,
                         method = extratrees_para,
                         metric = "ROC",
                         trControl = trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv',
                                                  repeats=1,
                                                  classProb = T,
                                                  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary),
                         ntree = 3000, 
                         tuneGrid = extratreesGrid)
```

However, I keep getting this error message which is not very informative

"Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
  final tuning parameters could not be determined
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
2: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  missing values found in aggregated results"

Below is my session information. I would be really appreciated if anyone can help me with this. Thanks!

```
sessioninfo()

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] DMwR_0.4.1           BiocInstaller_1.16.5 caret_6.0-41        
[4] ggplot2_1.0.0        lattice_0.20-29      extraTrees_1.0.5    
[7] rJava_0.9-6         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] abind_1.4-3         bitops_1.0-6        BradleyTerry2_1.0-5
[4] brglm_0.5-9         car_2.0-24          caTools_1.17.1     
[7] class_7.3-11        codetools_0.2-9     colorspace_1.2-4   
[10] compiler_3.1.2      digest_0.6.8        e1071_1.6-4          
[13] foreach_1.4.2       gdata_2.16.1        gplots_2.17.0      
[16] gtable_0.1.2        gtools_3.4.1        iterators_1.0.7    
[19] KernSmooth_2.23-13  lme4_1.1-7          MASS_7.3-35        
[22] Matrix_1.1-4        mgcv_1.8-3          minqa_1.2.4        
[25] munsell_0.4.2       nlme_3.1-118        nloptr_1.0.4       
[28] nnet_7.3-8          parallel_3.1.2      pbkrtest_0.4-2     
[31] plyr_1.8.1          pROC_1.8            proto_0.3-10       
[34] quantmod_0.4-4      quantreg_5.11       Rcpp_0.11.4        
[37] reshape2_1.4.1      ROCR_1.0-7          rpart_4.1-8        
[40] scales_0.2.4        SparseM_1.6         splines_3.1.2      
[43] stringr_0.6.2       tools_3.1.2         TTR_0.22-0         
[46] xts_0.9-7           zoo_1.7-12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it could generate class probabilities when I first added the model. I'm not sure why your version didn't work but here is what I'm adding to the package:

```
modelInfo <- list(label = "Random Forest by Randomization",
                  library = c("extraTrees"),
                  loop = NULL,
                  type = c('Regression', 'Classification'),
                  parameters = data.frame(parameter = c('mtry', 'numRandomCuts'),
                                          class = c('numeric', 'numeric'),
                                          label = c('# Randomly Selected Predictors', '# Random Cuts')),
                  grid = function(x, y, len = NULL){
                    expand.grid(mtry = var_seq(p = ncol(x), 
                                               classification = is.factor(y), 
                                               len = len), 
                                numRandomCuts = 1:len)
                  },
                  fit = function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...) 
                    extraTrees(x, y, mtry = param$mtry, numRandomCuts = param$numRandomCuts, ...),
                  predict = function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL)
                    predict(modelFit, newdata),
                  prob = function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL)
                    predict(modelFit, newdata, probability = TRUE),
                  levels = function(x) x$obsLevels,
                  tags = c("Random Forest", "Ensemble Model", "Bagging", "Implicit Feature Selection"),
                  sort = function(x) x[order(x[,1]),])
```

Comment: thanks so much for the package developer to respond me so quick! I think I have the same model design as you. But still I can not make it work (I will try again this morning).

Comment: Another question. I am always wondering if I can find a description of the design of your package. I know that every model have their defined modules like 'label', 'library', 'fit', 'predict', etc. But how can I get a better understanding of how caret exactly works? Like After I constructed the model and called train function. What functions will be called sequentially? From my understanding, after train function has been called, 1. preprocess steps 2. random resamples will be generated as specified

Comment: 3. models will be trained for models in the loop variable by using the fit function for each model 4. Specified metrics will be calculated and final model parameters will be identified 5. A final model will be constructed by using the final model.

Comment: Turns out that I have an older version of caret and extraTrees. I updated the two packages and everything works fine now.